# Create a Python dictionary containing specific key–value pairs from another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some code that looks something like this:

```
d = {'foo': True, 'bar': 42, 'baz': '!'}

a = {'foo': d['foo'], 'bar': d['bar']}
b = {'foo': d['foo'], 'baz': d['baz']}
c = {'bar': d['bar'], 'baz': d['baz']}
```

Surely there's a better way to express this. I actually read the docs in the hope that a dictionary's `copy` method accepts keys to be included in the new dictionary:

```
# I'd hoped that something like this would work...
a = d.copy('foo', 'bar')
b = d.copy('foo', 'baz')
c = d.copy('bar', 'baz')
```

I could write a function for this purpose:

```
copydict = lambda dct, *keys: {key: dct[key] for key in keys}

a = copydict(d, 'foo', 'bar')
b = copydict(d, 'foo', 'baz')
c = copydict(d, 'bar', 'baz')
```

Is there a better solution than the above?

Comment: Why don't you use a list (or a set) for a,b,c? You cold look the value up in d when you need it.

Comment: I'm actually passing `a`, `b`, and `c` to Django's `urlencode` function (which, like `urllib.urlencode`, accepts a dictionary).

Comment: @BlaXpirit: you should write an answer containing just "No." (pad to the minimum size with an HTML comment) so that we can all madly vote it up.

Comment: In case you're interested, I posted a related question, about going one better than copying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329537/python-create-own-dict-view-of-subset-of-dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that the function in the question is the best solution.

Of course, someone could post some idiomatic code, but I'm sure it wouldn't work better/faster. Iterating over a list and getting items from a dict by key is as fast as it can get.

One suggestion is to remove the star from the `keys` parameter. Argument unpacking adds unnecessary overhead. There should be no problem with just passing those keys as a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

The only improvement I would make is to use a real function definition, not a lambda:

```
def copy_dict(d, *keys):
    """Make a copy of only the `keys` from dictionary `d`."""
    return {key: d[key] for key in keys}
```

It could be useful to deal with missing keys, but in Python 2 you can't mix optional keyword arguments with *args nicely, so you might have to go to a tuple argument:

```
def copy_dict(d, keys, default=None):
    """Make a copy of only the `keys` from dictionary `d`.

    Use `default` if a key is missing.

    """
    return {key: d.get(key, default) for key in keys}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @BlaXpirit, this solution probably isn't going to be better than yours in terms of speed or readability, but you could do something like this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d = {'foo': True, 'bar': 42, 'baz': '!'}
>>> keys = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> dict(zip(keys, itemgetter(*keys)(d)))
{'bar': 42, 'foo': True}
```